# How to enable logging / debugging for openssl in android.

Tags: android, logging, openssl

I am currently working on an assignment in openssl in android.

I have access to the code. and I can add custom logs in it if i want.

But the problem is these logs dont appear in the logcat.

Is there any specific setting / property /flag that I need to change to enable logs from openssl in android?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any specific setting / property /flag that I need to change to enable logs from openssl in android?

The OpenSSL library does not log. There is a `BIO_s_log`, but its not really used anywhere:

```
openssl-1.0.1h$ grep -R BIO_s_log *
crypto/bio/bio.h:BIO_METHOD *BIO_s_log(void);
crypto/bio/bss_log.c:   Why BIO_s_log?
crypto/bio/bss_log.c:   BIO_s_log is useful for system daemons (or services under NT).
crypto/bio/bss_log.c:BIO_METHOD *BIO_s_log(void)
util/libeay.num:BIO_s_log                               1243    EXIST:!OS2,!WIN16,!WIN32,!macintosh:FUNCTION:
util/mkdef.pl:  $platform{"BIO_s_log"} .= ",!WIN32,!WIN16,!macintosh";
```